# Why doesn't Xcode have a Event/Arguments when linking an object with an IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibaction

I'm a complete newbie with Objective-C, Xcode, and the design itself. I have had a bit more experience developing iOS on Xcode, and when you wanted to link an action (i.e Slider changing value), you could select from many options unlike OS X.
How can I get around this with the same results, as using a pre-generated (control-drag slider to ViewController.h and .m) only fires an action at the mouseUp action.

EDIT #1: Sorry for making my question quite confusing. I am wondering how to receive actions **while** dragging.

Here's whats happening in picture form:

[image: As you ca see, there is no arguments or event option]

Most likely something very easy that I'm not getting at all.

Comment: either u haven't set the viewcontroller class in storyboard or your xcode need a restart

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not set controller from Storyboard. Please verify your controller class is properly set by following the image below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think that is the problem currently for me. I wanted to receive multiple actions from the slider. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confused. Are you trying to ask how to make a slider send its message while dragging, instead of just at the end?

On Mac, controls only have one target/action, there are no multiple actions. Objects have other properties that control when the actions are actually sent, if needed. In case of NSSlider, you probably forgot to set its 'continuous' property.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear. I didn't understand that there are no multiple actions. Sorry that my question was quite hard to understand